# Refreshing a div in Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a modal with two div user can add items by clicking on the button on the first div but as the user select that item i want to show the selected item in the second div. I am able to insert the selected item in database but i am unable to refresh the second div. So that user can see what item he has selected, Here is my jQuery code

```
function PreCont(cont_id) { //THIS FUNCTION ADD ITEM IN DB{
  var nit = $('#contractor').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data/add_pre_cont.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      nit: nit,
      cont_id: cont_id,    
    },
    success: function() {
      display_pre_cont(nit); // HERE I AM TRYING TO REFRESH THE DIV BY CALLING A FUNCTION   
    },
    error: function() {},   
  });
}
```

This function is trying to display the data

```
function display_pre_cont(nit) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data/pre_cont_modal.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      nit:nit,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#pre-contractor').html(data);  
    },
    error: function (data){},
  });
}
```

My code works fine if I refresh it i can see the new items

HTML Code

```
<div> // First Div
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="myTable-item-order" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
          <thead><tr>
              <th width="5%"><center>Cate.</center></th>
              <th width="5%"><center>Enlist</center></th>
              <th width="41%"><center>Contractor Name</center></th>
              <th width="19%"><center>District</center></th>
              <th width="9%"><center></center></th>
          </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
<?php foreach($valid_contractor as $v): ?>
<tr align="center">
       <td width="15%"><?= $v['category']; ?></td>
       <td><?= $v['reionno']; ?></td>
       <td align="left"><?= ucwords($v['contractorname']) ?></td>
       <td align="left"><?= ucwords($v['district']) ?></td>
       <td>
       <button onclick="PreCont('<?= $v['id']; ?>');" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </button>
      </td>
     </tr>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

2nd Div needs to be refreshed

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="pre-contractor">
   <? require_once('modal/pre_cont_modal.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: There's hundreds of reasons an AJAX request could fail. Check the console for errors first to try and find some clues as to why it's 'not working' - or better yet, actually put some logic in the `error` handlers to debug the problem

Comment: Can you post html code with the part of modal  because it's difficult to tell what is wrong

Comment: What does data contain in your success callback?